# Does the vmware vCenter api support summary metrics across multiple vms?

Tags: api, virtual-machine, vmware, metrics, vcenter

Does the vCenter 6.7 API have a summary metrics endpoint across vms in a cluster?

or

Do i have to make an API call for each VM and aggregate all the data later.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance Manager service is going to be your best resource for this question: https://code.vmware.com/apis/704/vsphere/vim.PerformanceManager.html

Cliff's notes: The cluster level will have limited amount of metrics that can be sourced and summarized as VM stats, so it will really depend on what metrics you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The version of vcenter i am working with(6.7.0.42) does not have update 3 installed. I only have access to the REST api. Are the summary metrics under the appliance/ endpoint? I have not been able to find any metrics under the vcenter/ endpoint.